# Mad Monk Theory (Unprediactable and Wreckless (but genius) Model)

Tags: poker-strategy

I apologize, I'm not a math person, I am a Poker player.     We all talk about Game Theory optimal play at the table, but one time I was talking to a wealthy business man who told me about a mathmatical model that the nuclear missle systems use called "mad monk".  This is what I remember..    Basically the best way in the event of a nuclear arms race or a nuclear missle crisis is to have an unpredicatable automatic missle system that is "mad".    Because it's "mad", all other models don;t work properly when competing against it. And so I wish to understand this more...

I am a game theory optimal and exploitive player who let my little brother play yesterday.  He is new and was just having fun with the game.   He was of course a "mad" player and his buy in (with the help of some luck...  whether it was actual luck or caused by his strategy) went from $2 to $20.   People paid him off big time on his good hands, while he lost a healthy amount on his bad hands, but still made 10x his buyins.

My question is how can I learn more about this type of game play / mathmatical model?     There has to be a name for the model I can lookup or research some more..   Im just looking for a name or some kind of direction for finding out more information to something like this because "mad monk theory" doesnt come up in google.    Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Dan Harrington Talks about the doubling cube and seemingly irrational pushes in NLHE in one of his books in his serious of three. It seems to be basically the same thing, The tactics work because calling the bet in a poker tournament, or a huge double, because while the call is favorable in the long run, it puts you at a risk they you can better overcome by doing something like grinding.

A new player like your bro, is a little scary and unpredictable. Therefore, they sometimes play in a mad style, and often, will come out very good for awhile. A number of people at times play in this way, others play this way as a game style. In the hands of a seasoned player it can work great. its downsides are a much higher deviation. Stu Unger played this way. Phill Hellmuth plays this way at times. Almost all players who have a meteoric rise play this way. Being able to play mad is often the way to play a game, other times it will just get you busted.